screen magnifier gestures active only for specific apps on android
screen magnifier gestures active only for specific apps on android
In android 6.0.1, there is: system config / accessibility / vision / magification gestures. But it is bad because it ignores the fact that I need to use it only with a single app...
Searching about it on the play store, is only bringing results for camera magnification.
I am looking for an app that only enables screen magnification gestures for specified applications.
